# Seeding Membership with custom data Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the fallowing Models

```
namespace Prometheus.Models
{
    [Table("People")]
    public class Person : IPerson
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
            set{}
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And one that inherits it

```
namespace Prometheus.Models
{
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile : Person
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string CNP { get; set; }
        public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
        public bool? IsUSAMV { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the seed method

```
private void AddUser(string user, string password,
    SimpleMembershipProvider membership)
{
    if (membership.GetUser(user, false) == null)
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(user, password, new
        {
            CNP = "1890531111111",
            IsUSAMV = true,
        });
    }
}
```

When i try to run the seed method without UserProfile extending Person everything is ok, but when it extends it i keep getting the fallowing error.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.People_Id". The conflict occurred in database "PrometheusDb", table "dbo.People", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I tried updateing my function to

```
private void AddUser(string firstName,string lastName, string password,
    SimpleMembershipProvider membership)
{
    var user = firstName + "." + lastName;
    if (membership.GetUser(user, false) == null)
    {
        var profile = new UserProfile()
        {
            Email = "test@email.com",
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName
        };
        _context.Users.Add(profile);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(user, password);
    }
}
```

But now i get:
- **An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserProfile' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

Comment: for what I see UserProfile have a Foreing Key with Person, when you are creating the new UserAndAcount you never set the value of that Foreing Key.

Comment: @Guillelon You might be right but i don't really know how to do it from what you said i think i should create the person first and then when creating the UserProfile i should set the Id pointing to it, it that correct ?

Comment: yes that's how I think is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a problem in the order that items are created and the integrity checks on the db.  I have done something similar and it has involved saving the user first then the account.  My code looks like:

```
var user = new User { UserName = model.UserName, Organisation = userOrg };
this.repository.SaveUser(user);
string token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, true);
```

Notice the use of the `CreateAccount` rather than the `CreateUserAndAccount` method

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but that didn't quite work, i changed my function but now i get a new different error, i've updated my question can you please help. Thank you

Comment: Is the error on the _context.SaveChanges or the WebSecurity.CreateAccount line ?  If it is on the _context.SaveChanges you probably want to check the mappings on the model between People and UserProfile