# Identity Specification false Entity Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the fallowing 2 classes:

```
[Table("People")]
    public class Person : IPerson
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            Results = new Collection<Result>();
        }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
            set{}
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
[Table("UserProfile")]

    public class UserProfile : Person
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            Faculty = new Faculty();
            Projects = new Collection<Project>();
        }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string CNP { get; set; }
        public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

Every time i use EF CodeFirst to generate my DB, and try too run the seed method i get an error. **An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserProfile' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.** You can find more about it here [Seeding Membership with custom data Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934366/seeding-membership-with-custom-data-entity-framework)

I found out that to fix it after running `update-database` from the package manager console i have to open the table in server explorer and set `Idendtity Specification` to false for the **Id** in the **UsersProfile** table, my question is can i do something to my model so that i won't have to this every time i regenerate my Db.

I tried the answer from here [Identity specification set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829911/identity-specification-set-to-false) but because of the inheritance (i think) i get

```
Conflicting configuration settings were specified for property 'Id' on type 'Prometheus.Models.Person': 
    DatabaseGeneratedOption = None conflicts with DatabaseGeneratedOption = Identity
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happens in the seed method? What is "an error"?

Comment: Do you want `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` or `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`? Which problem needs fixing here? The conflict or the Seed? If it's the conflict do you have any Fluent API code in `OnModelCreating`? If it's the `Seed` please show us that code and error.

Comment: @GertArnold hello the error is An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserProfile' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. You can find more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934366/seeding-membership-with-custom-data-entity-framework

Comment: @Colin I honestly don't really know, i think it's none for the table "UserProfile" and DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity for People, but UserProfile inherits from People, that's my problem. Updated the question with the error i get if don't set the Idendtity Specification to false

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure exactly what is happening here but I do know the `UserProfile` table is often created with a call to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` rather than the migrations code and that's going to put in an IDENTITY field. So there is a conflict between `WebSecurity` and Entity Framework here.

Then you are adding inheritance into the picture and because you have specified table names it is [Table per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) - and Entity Framework wants that to use a [shared primary key](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx). So it probably does not want the `UserProfile` table to have an IDENTITY field.

I think you hit the nail on the head when you said

> ```
> UserProfile inherits from People, that's my problem
> ```

I would change that relationship so that `Person` *has a* `UserProfile` instead. I think that models the real world more accurately and if you ever have any people who aren't users it will be easier to make the relationship optional. Like this:

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person : IPerson
{
    //avoids virtual call in constructor
    private ICollection<Result> _Results;

    public Person()
    {
        _Results = new Collection<Result>();
    }

    //no annotations required. 
    //An int field named Id is a database generated key by convention
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Person has a UserProfile (optional)
    public int? UserProfileID { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    //etc

    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results
    {
        get { return _Results; }
        set { _Results = value; }
    }
}

public class UserProfile : ModelBase
{
    //UserProfile is always related to a Person
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Person { get; set; }

    //etc
}
```

<strike>You will also find loads of stuff about [preferring composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).</strike>

Otherwise you need to dig in to the migrations to get the tables created in the way that supports TPT - but you should also be aware that [switching identity on/off in migrations does not happen automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342).Perhaps you could create the `UserProfile` table in a migration instead of with `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`

Comment: Sorry for not specifying it in my question i am calling WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection in my seed function. I don't think that composition over inheritance is an option for me because of the way that the application has to work and besides for EF i need the default constructor.

Comment: OK that was probably a bad link to put in. See the code I've added in my edit